# Stream text file from client to server?

Tags: node.js, meteor

So I have a use case where the client uploads a small TSV file, the file is opened and parsed on the server, and results are written to a new file on the server.

Since the TSV file will be tiny (under 1 MB), I am wondering if it is even necessary to upload the file to the server (writing it to disk) before parsing it. Instead, could the file contents be captured when the user clicks "upload file"? I could then store the file contents in an array, each item representing a line in the file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stream the file to disk, but be aware that you should set clear and concise limits so that a person could not, say, upload a 5GB file and make your service crash from memory exhaustion. You just need to be aware that you're limited to your available amount of memory(likely less) when you process something completely in memory. It's also possible to stream parse it, so that you don't need to save it to disk before parsing it. In your case it sounds easiest to just upload it into memory, and make certain that you put a limit(maybe like 5mb limit) on the upload file size.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether this option is feasible or whether it's a good idea?

Regarding feasibility, it is entirely possible using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to parse the content and then a simple `Meteor.call` onto whatever method is appending to the file on disk. The code would like like follows:

```
function onSubmit(event, template) {
    var file = template.$('.your-file-input-elemt').files[0];
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.onload = function(fileevent) {
        Meteor.call('processTSV', filereader.readAsText(file));
    };
}
```

If you're talking about whether it's a good idea, then it comes down to browser support. Are you okay with users without the FileReader API not getting support from your application? If so it's considerably easier to deal with than handling uploads with something like CollectionFS.